# Anchor <a> tags not loading components instantly in Chrome when using #

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to call components on the same page from Navbar in a react application using anchor tags. Here is the code:

```
<li><a href="/#contact">Contact</a></li>
```

The component it supposed to call is the following:

```
<div id="contact"></div>
```

In Chrome, components are not loading instantly after clicking on the navbar. Browser only scrolls down after the page is loaded. However, these anchors tags works instantly in IE&FF. I even tried to use Lazy and Suspense to optimize the application loading performance. Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Have you tried out using React router?

Comment: Is it possible to route to components on the same page using react-router? @axtck

Comment: Yes, and with barely any delay, if you wish I could explain it to you

Comment: Yes, if you could give an example that would be great. @axtck

Comment: Did you check out the example I posted using React router? Consider giving some feedback, greetings

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try out [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

First, install the packages with npm or yarn:

`npm install react-router-dom` or `yarn add react-router-dom`

What I like to do for making routing possible is packing my `<App />` component in a `<BrowserRouter />` component from React Router (in index.js) like this:

```js
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; // import BrowserRouter

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Don't forget to `import` the module.

Now, you can use a `<Switch />` component from React Router on the place where you would like to render your components, take a look at this example for a simple blog:

```js
<Switch>
  {/* blogs routes */}
  <Route path="/blogs/create" component={CreateBlog} />
  <Route path="/blogs/:blogId" component={BlogPostList} />
  <Route path="/blogs" component={BlogList} />

  {/* redirect to blogs when visiting wrong route */}
  <Redirect to="/blogs" />
</Switch>
```

As you can see, inside the `<Switch />`, you can specify routes by using the `<Route />` component and with a corresponding `path` and the `component` you would like to render. You can also provide a `<Redirect />` to redirect the user when entering a non-existing route. Also note that the least specific route (*/blogs*) comes after a more specific route (*/blogs/create*), this is because the router will stop searching after the first match.

To navigate to a specific route from code, you can use `useHistory()` from React Router like this example that navigates on a click from a button. `history.push('route')` will push a route and will render the component specified for that route.

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleClick = () => {
    history.push("/blogs/1");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to blog 1</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For local/same-page links to IDs don't use the slash in the `a` tag's `href` attribute (like `href="/#contact"`), but only the hash, like this: `href="#contact"`